# Как импортировать Java проект из GitLab в IDEA?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gitlab

Как импортировать проект из GitLab в IDEA?

Comment: `Взяли на практику как Java-Junior, ура!` кто ?

Comment: [Как импортировать Java проект из GitLab в IDEA](https://githowto.com/ru/cloningrepositories)

Comment: @JVic ответы в ответ